# Angular detect end of day time from data Json

Tags: angular

I have following weather JSON struncture:

```
{
  "id": "36.19,44.00",
  "vt1hourlyForecast": {
    "processTime": [
      "2019-08-12T17:00:00+0300",
      "2019-08-12T18:00:00+0300",
      "2019-08-12T19:00:00+0300",
      "2019-08-12T20:00:00+0300",
      "2019-08-12T21:00:00+0300",
      "2019-08-12T22:00:00+0300",
      "2019-08-12T23:00:00+0300",
      "2019-08-13T00:00:00+0300",
      "2019-08-13T01:00:00+0300",
      "2019-08-13T02:00:00+0300",
      "2019-08-13T03:00:00+0300",
      "2019-08-13T04:00:00+0300",
      "2019-08-13T05:00:00+0300",
      "2019-08-13T06:00:00+0300",
      "2019-08-13T07:00:00+0300",
      "2019-08-13T08:00:00+0300"
    ],
    "temperature": [
      45,
      44,
      42,
      39,
      38,
      37,
      36,
      34,
      33,
      33,
      32
    ]
  }
}
```

l am working on angular to get weather Json hourly above . I want to separate time for the end of day like image below .

[image]

What i did :
 `{{hourly.vt1hourlyForecast.processTime[7] | date:'shortTime'}}` ,

but l can not use array number [7] because data json arrays always updating and in that case he can not detect the current time for the end of day. Any solution please ?

Comment: I would suggest using moment.js to group times according to dates.

Comment: Thank you for replying . Do you have any examples please ?